# Fiberwise isomorphism vs local isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\to B$ and $g:Y \to B$ be two morphisms of varieties over $\mathbb C$. If for every closed point $b\in B$, the fibers $f^{-1}(b)$ and $g^{-1}(b)$ are isomorphic. I want to know that if they are locally isomorphic? i.e., can we find an open set $U$ for every $b\in B$ such that $f|_{f^{-1}(U)}$ and $g|_{g^{-1}(U)}$ are isomorphic?

If not (which I tend to believe), under what conditions can it be true?

Comment: The simplest counterexample is a nontrivial etale covering $X \to B$ and a trivial etale covering $Y \to B$ of the same degree.

Comment: Dear @Sasha: but why they are not locally isomorphic?

Comment: I think your wording is confusing - if you're asking whether you can find an open set $U$ such that $f|_{f^{-1}(U)}$ is an isomorphism, then what is the role of $g$ here?

Comment: @Akatsuki: Assuming $B$ is normal and integral, an etale covering $X$ is equal to the normal closure of $B$ in the field of rational functions on $X$; in particular it is determined by $X_U \to U$ for any Zariski open subset $U \subset B$.

Comment: Do you mean Zariski open or analytic open ? This changes a lot.

Comment: @loch Yes. I mean if the two families $f$ and $g$ are isomorphic. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Sasha I see. So, if there is any known condition to ensure the local isomorphism?

Comment: Dear @NicolasHemelsoet: Now I see it is not true for the Zariski open set. Is it true for tthe analytic open?

Comment: @Akatsuki: If you assume the morphisms are smooth, then in the analytic topology it is true by Ehresmann's fibration theorem.

Comment: @Sasha Many thanks!

Comment: @Akatsuki : Hi, sorry for the late reply. In the analytic case I don't know a counter-example in general, if $f$ is proper and smooth you can conclude using Ehresmann's theorem. (I'm not sure how to conclude without the properness hypothesis)